# Can RFC Calls built for the communication between SAP to SAP be used for SAP to Non SAP communication

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, saprfc

Can RFC Calls built for the communication betweenSAP to SAP be used for SAP to Non SAP communication in which non SAP(Dynamics CRM) is at receiving end.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Obviously.](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm50/helpdata/de/a1/530408511c0347ae30bdae9e71a00b/frameset.htm) - looks like very poor research to me, voting to close...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster apparently didn't do any research on the topic before asking.

Comment: @vwegert  how it this a poor research? the question not to connect between the sap to non sap system . question is regarding the usage of the sap to sap RFC interface for sap to non sap system

Comment: @vwegert I know the options which you have provided. I want to use the same RFC developed previously for SAP - SAP to communicate between SAP - Non SAP

Comment: SAP .Net Connector comes with samples for SAP to non-SAP RFC calls (RFC server sample). Please check them out.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek thanks for the comment. Yes this is one of the option because SAP to SAP calls are completed trusted communication, same channel cannot be used SAP to non-SAP communication which will be different form of communication